# Replace 0xC0<byte> with 0xC000 to "reset" MIDI instrument?

Tags: midi, midi-instrument

I've got some MIDI files made by Sibelius (v.4?..) with "unusual" instrument within; I can not hear the melody. I decided that I need to "reset" instrument to 0 (Acoustic Grand Piano, I believe).

So, I wrote a Python programs using both [python-midi](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi/) and [mingus](http://code.google.com/p/mingus/); these programs could change MIDI instrument, but they both changed rhythm dramatically.

[Rosegarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/) does this job quite well, but I can not use it in a batch.

Next, after some reading of MIDI format information ([here](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html) and [here](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm), for instance) I wrote a simple Python script (see below), which simply replaces some strings with another ones --- replaces 0xC0[byte] with 0xC000 and like that.

Now those MIDI files sounds OK, I can hear everything.

So, my question is --- is it "safe" (in any meaning) to do this? How I can change instruments better? How I can "detect" 0xCx command in MIDI file better?

Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

import sys
import re

patt = re.compile('(\xC0|\xC1|\xC2|\xC3|\xC4|\xC5|\xC6|\xC7).')

try:
    filein = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "Specify input file as an argument."
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    fileout = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    fileout = '%s-out2.mid' % filein.replace('.mid', '')

filein_data = open(filein, 'rb').read()

open(fileout, 'wb').write(patt.sub('\1\x00',filein_data))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe to simply replace all 0xC??? bytes with 0xC?00, mainly because 0xC??? could be indicating an event's delta time and not actually be part of a Program Change event. Accidentally modifying a delta time will shift all subsequent events off-time, which will sound pretty awful if it's part of a multi-track composition.

As for a solution, I doubt there's a regex that can detect Program Change events without possibly picking up delta times as well. My only experience with modifying MIDI is with the [Java library](http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/) I wrote, and you would accomplish your task with the following code:

```
MidiFile input = new MidiFile(INPUT_FILE);

for(MidiTrack T : input.getTracks()) {
    Iterator<MidiEvent> it = T.getEvents().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        MidiEvent E = it.next();
        if(E instanceof ProgramChange) {
            E.setProgramNumber(0);
        }
    }
}

input.writeToFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
```

I wrote that free-hand so you'll likely have to use some exception catching, but it's fairly straight-forward.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So, `\xC???` can be a part of time delta ("in between" or the last, depending on the least sign. bit) or be a Program Change event (for any track). Right? Well.. I think I should wrote some script using `python-midi`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Dontknow what's wrong prevoiusly. `python-midi` is nice.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Sets all instruments' numbers to zero.
#

import sys
import midi

try:
    infile = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "Specify input file as an argument, please."
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    outfile = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    outfile = '%s-out.mid' % infile.replace('.mid', '')

midi_data = midi.read_midifile(infile)

for track_idx in range(len(midi_data)):
    for event in midi_data[track_idx]:
        if isinstance(event, midi.ProgramChangeEvent):
            event.data = map(lambda x: 0, event.data)

midi.write_midifile(outfile, midi_data)
```

Comment: I feel this isn't an answer to the presented question. This is the solution reached after receiving the answer, but if anyone else has this question, this doesn't provide any education on the topic. That said, I'm glad you reached a solution! :-)

Comment: @LeffelMania Yes, probably. I was wrong having asked three questions in one. I will un-select my answerr, too.